# Auto Refresh Short Code (not entire page)

Tags: wordpress, refresh

I am not a web developer and have a non-profit event tonight where we would like to refresh HTML short code every few minutes without having to refresh the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the short code:

[classy-campaign-progress id="14608" title="My Big Campaign Progress Bar"]

I have the plugin installed and is working however it only refreshes on page refresh.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Classy, but I'm afraid there's no simple solution for that. Basically you would need to make a custom plugin that supports live data loading from their API and live refreshing on your page using JavaScript/AJAX.

Why exactly is refreshing the page an issue? If you just don't want to do it manually, you could set up **auto refresh using a browser extension** ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/tab-auto-refresh/), [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/search/auto%20refresh)).